# Reden, wie einem der Schnabel gewachsen ist

Tags: meaning, translation, idiom

What does this German sentence mean?

> Reden, wie einem der Schnabel gewachsen ist.
>
> „Du hast eine entzückende Art zu plaudern, wie dir der Schnabel
>   gewachsen ist.“

Comment: Did you try googling it?

Comment: Of course.  Why?

Comment: And you didn't find any answers to this question? I wonder why you post a questions when looking for the answer is so easy.

Comment: "German Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question-and answer site for speakers of all levels who want to share and increase their knowledge of the German language. Questions in both, English and German are welcome."
Ich denke, Sinn und Zweck dieser Seite ist Leuten zu helfen, die Deutsch lernen wollen. Das heisst für mich  "German Language & Usage... Natürlich weiss ich selber die Anworten auf meine Fragen, aber sie sollen anderen Gelegenheit bieten, ihre Kenntnisse zu erweitern und dafür belohnt zu werden.
Ich hoffe, du verstehst jetzt meine Absicht.

Comment: I don't think those "I am not interested in an anwer, but I post them anyway to help someone" questions help. How about a general post/answer about "how to understand an German idiom. Where do I find idiom dictionaries (with German and/or English explainations? Where can I find informations about the origins of idioms?"

Comment: "how to understand a German idiom. Where do I find idiom dictionaries (with German and/or English explainations? Where can I find informations about the origins of idioms?" that's exactly how I first posted the question, I don't know whether you can follow up my edition. But probably you are right:
I might have asked (and this was an alternative way of questioning I was thinking about: give in a the English translations and ask what would be a good German idiom that will say this: https://www.dict.cc/?s=schnabel+gewachsen.
There are some points I maybe should discuss in the meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to talk without concern for conventions, to say what one thinks

see [2) here](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS14209#XGS14209)

Comment: great link! and even with downloadable Pdf. many thanks!